# Simple question about the source of variation after fixed effects

Tags: fixed-effects-model, intuition

Could you please give me the intuition of where does the variation comes from a fixed effects regression? I understand the simpler structures, such as:

$y_{it}=\beta_0+\beta_1x_{it}+\alpha_i+\alpha_t+\varepsilon_{it},$

where the variation comes from within units as deviation from the time-specific average. But I have a more difficult time seeing the source of variation here:

$y_{ijt}=\beta_0+\beta_1x_{ijt}+\alpha_{ij}+\alpha_{it}+\alpha_{jt}+\varepsilon_{ijt}.$

Say $i$ denotes the country, $j$ denotes the sector, $t$ denotes the year. Where does the variation come from? What is the (statistical or geometrical) intuition? Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Do you have a reference?